# Detect if Shitfkey is pressed

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm having some problem detecting if [shiftkey] is pressed because it's always changed.

[image]

As you can see, now the `va` attribut has the MouseEvents.

#### file.js

```
function createInfobar(elem, event) {
 if( event.va.shiftKey ){//...}

}
```

This code above used to work just fine,. But then it started to detect the event as `undefined`. Then I changed to `event.xa.shiftkey` and it worked.
Now, checking the `event` on the console, it's `VA.ShitfKey` again...

How could I fix it ? Is there a way to get it with all browsers ?

Comment: is this keypress event or keydown event?

Comment: SOrry, guess it's `keyDown`. Need to check if I clicked while shitftKey is down/pressed...

Comment: Can you create a code snippet via `<>` so that we can replicate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```js
function isKeyPressed(event) {
var x = document.getElementById("out");
if (event.shiftKey) {
    x.innerHTML = "The SHIFT pressed!";
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "The SHIFT NOT pressed!";
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="isKeyPressed(event)">
<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. Already tried with `event.shiftKey` only and it says: `Can't read shiftkey from undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        console.log("shift key")
    } else {
        console.log("some other key")
    }
});
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet of catching the keyup & keydown.

Remember to click the snippet first so it receives keyboard input.

```js
let elshift = document.querySelector(".shift-pressed");


document.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  if (ev.key === "Shift")
    elshift.innerText = "Shift DOWN";
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (ev) {
  if (ev.key === "Shift")
    elshift.innerText = "Shift UP";
});
```

```html
<div class="shift-pressed">
  Please note click this first to make snippet have focus..
</div>
```